# Methods of storing time interval into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am building a web application that requires the storage of a time interval.

Examples:

- 1 Hour
- 1 Hour and 30 Mins
- 2 Hours
- 2 Hours and 30 Mins

I'm going to use the interval within the following three ways:

1. The time interval is selected by the user and stored within the database.
2. The time interval is displayed as plain text within the interface ('1 Hour').
3. The time interval is used within a function as milliseconds.

I would like to know some of the ways to store this time interval with the database and be used within the functionalities above.

Currently I have the interval stored within the database as an int(in milliseconds). The user will select from a drop down menu. So if they select "1 hour", the value for that selection would be 1 hour in milliseconds which is 3600000, then I can use it within a function. A slight issue arises when it's time to display "1 Hour" within the interface.

Another method I assume is to store the interval within the database as a string and then use a function to strip the values. Example: [1]hours [30]mins.

I'm using PHP and JavaScript by the way. The PHP is strictly server-side and JavaScript client-side.

Comment: What about using [ISO 8601 Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) as used by PHP's [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php); or by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) with the [moment-interval](https://github.com/luisfarzati/moment-interval)  extension

Comment: Whilst you might be needing to use it in javascript as milliseconds, are you needing millisecond precision? I'd store it as minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that should be handled entirely by PHP - both the insertion of the time into the database, and the formatted output.

I would recommend having the selections have `values` that directly correspond to their respective seconds (60 seconds to a minute, 3600 seconds to an hour):

```
<option value="3600">One hour</option>
<option value="5400">One hour and thirty minutes</option>
```

I would then store the times as seconds in the database:

```
$time = 3600;
"INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ($time)";
```

You would then retrieve it from the database (in this case using `$time`), and format it with **[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)**:

```
$hours = floor($time / 3600);
$minutes = ($time / 60) % 60;
$seconds = $time % 60;
$format = '%d hour(s), %d minute(s) and %d second(s)';
echo sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
// 1 hour(s), 30 minute(s) and 0 second(s)
```

Feel free to adapt to suit the desired output.

Note that you **may** also need to set a default timezone (based on your exact application), which can be done with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('[ZONE]');
```

That will ensure that all users see the same time, regardless of where they are in the world.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do this with html markup by using a select dropdown element and setting the 'value' attribute for each option element. Example: `<select><option value="3600000">1 hour</option></select>` (where 3600000 is the value being sent in the request and '1 hour' is what is displayed to the user).

Here is a complete test case:

```
<form method="POST" target="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <select name="interval">
        <option value="3600000"<?php echo isset($_POST['interval']) && (int)$_POST['interval'] === 3600000 ? 'selected':''; ?>>1 hour</value>
        <option value="5400000"<?php echo isset($_POST['interval']) && (int)$_POST['interval'] === 5400000 ? 'selected':''; ?>>1 hour and 30 minutes</value>
        <option value="7200000"<?php echo isset($_POST['interval']) && (int)$_POST['interval'] === 7200000 ? 'selected':''; ?>>2 hours</value>
        <option value="9000000"<?php echo isset($_POST['interval']) && (int)$_POST['interval'] === 9000000 ? 'selected':''; ?>>2 hours and 30 minutes</value>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
/* TEST CASE: */
if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['interval'])){
        echo $_POST['interval'].' milliseconds.';
    }else{
        echo 'Interval not set';
    }

    /* TODO: code to insert into DB */
}
?>
```

For your reference:

[Select lists - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

I would question, though, whether or not you really need millisecond precision in this case- this might be overkill and a waste of storage and computation in the long run... from the surface, it looks like storing in minutes will do the trick.

Hope this helps you some.

Comment: Yeah, you didn't interpret the question right. An answer that I was looking for is above.